# Can't change properties of LinkButtons in CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton

I have rlly trouble with a imo simple thing i allready did like million times, but this time, I cant.

I have LinkButtons in my Gridview like

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="GVCon_TFEdit" runat="server" CssClass="eh_label_style" CommandArgument="Edit" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And those i have six times.
Allways one Edit and one Delete-LinkButton.

Then i try to change the visible of them in Codebehind at line 5 (if i comment it out, then on 6 etc):

```
1    protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
2            {
3                if (Session["Permissions"].ToString() == "User")
4                {
5                    GVComp_TFDelete.Visible = false;
6                    GVComp_TFEdit.Visible = false;
7                    GVCon_TFDelete.Visible = false;
8                    GVCon_TFEdit.Visible = false;
9                    GVMatr_TFDelete.Visible = false;
10                   GVMatr_TFEdit.Visible = false;
```

But it allways brings me the goodknown exception:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Well - I'm sure the object isnt null there anymore ?!
(And Session["Permissions"] isnt null for sure also, because it is getting his Status in PreLoad allready ...)

And maybe I have to tell you more, because i had problems with EXACTLY those LinkButtons bevore ^^
So - in those TemplateFields i had exactly the same LinkButtons, then i changed the name of those LB, and since then i couldnt use them in CodeBehind.
It was because they werent in the designerfile anymore ...
So i tried alot of tips I found evrywhere in the inet, also tips from here - but they didnt worked (Like rebuilding the designerfile, writing the LinkButtons new into the aspx-file also I  made sure that the file is in the right folder etc ...) Nothing worked.
So i added them by hand into the designer.cs. Now i can "use" them in the CodeBehind, but when I start debugging - it runs into this error.

Would be really nice if you could help me, this is so annoying ...

Comment: Btw tell me if you need any more code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a Gridview, you will have to use the event `RowDataBound` for the gridview.

And in that event, you will have to check for `e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow`.

After that, you can use

```
LinkButton lb = ((LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("GVCon_TFEdit"));
```

to get the linkbutton for the current row, and then use `lb.Visible = false;` or whatever code you need.

Comment: Is it possible to find it also by GV.FindControl in the PreRenderComplete ? I have the RowDataBound allready because i insert some stuff there, so it would be no problem. Just for interrest.

Comment: Theoretically, you can loop over all rows in your gridview as long as it is bound.

Comment: Okay :) But do you also know why it deleted the old LB from the designer.cs-file and didnt added the new one when i rebuilded it ? Just a bonusquestion, if you dont know it its also okay :D

Comment: It's not added so you're not able to make a reference to it, since it's not really there. :) It only exists when the grid is databound.

Answer (score 2):

You can find also with `RowCommand` event by this way

```
LinkButton name = (LinkButton)gridview.Rows[index].FindControl("lnkbtnActionNames");

name.visible=false;
```

Comment: Yeah, but i would need to have a RowCommand executed first, and i dont want any user(Admins only) to have those LinkButtons which would have a RowCommand.